# subprocess Popen stdin will only input and run after the script has finished

Tags: python, windows, cmd, subprocess, stdin

Description:

I was trying to make a shell that can be interactive on a chatting software, so I need a `cmd.exe` as a subprocess and pass strings into the process.

I have this:

```py
from subprocess import Popen
from subprocess import PIPE as p

proc = Popen("cmd",stdout=p,stdin=p,shell=True)
```

so usually what we do if we need to pass input to the process is by using `proc.stdin.write()`
but it seems that the string will only pass in and work after the python script is complete

for example, I have

```py
#same thing above
proc.stdin.write("ping 127.0.0.1".encode())
time.sleep(10)
```

the script will wait for 10 sec then pass and run the `ping` command.
which means it's impossible to get the result `stdout.read()` because there is nothing.

I have tried to use `subprocess.Popen.communicate()` but it closes the pipe after one input.

Is there any way to solve the "only run the command after script finish" thing, or make `communicate()` not close the pipe?

Comment: And yes I did pass  "\n" together with commands to make them run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writes to pipes are buffered, you need to flush the buffer.

```
proc.stdin.write("ping 127.0.0.1".encode())
proc.stdin.flush()
```

Comment: You can disable buffering on Python's side by passing `bufsize=0` to `Popen`. But regardless of whether you're using manual flushing or no buffering, this attempt at making an interactive shell is doomed to fail in general. It works pretty much only for CMD's internal commands and non-interactive external programs. Most interactive external programs will use full buffering on their side of a pipe. Individually they sometimes have environment-variable options or command-line options to disable buffering, but there is no generic way to address this in Windows when using pipes for standard I/O.